# Magento 2.4.4 setup:install Error : "the default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again."

Tags: configuration, config, magento2

I have gotten only the configuration value in the Helper file but when I put first my extension and then run setup:install command it gives this error "the default website isn't defined. Set the website and try again."

I have applied the below code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendore\Extension\Helper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    const SECTION_GROUP_FIELD = 'section/group/field';
    protected $storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    ) {
        $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    public function getConfigvalue()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::SECTION_GROUP_FIELD, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Any Solution regarding this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten that error mostly because Magento didn't like my `app/etc/env.php` file. Try moving it and then run `setup:install` again to see if it finishes.

You will have to append the newly created `env.php` with any customizations from your old file.

Answer (score 0):

remove env.php in Magento and try with upgrade

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).